# Angular JS Route перезагрузка страницы с параметром

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Есть такой роут

```
.when('/news/:newsId', {
    templateUrl: '/single-news.html',
    controller: 'singleNewsController'
})
```

При перезагрузке страницы получаю вместо http://joxi.ru/vAWXpkbI1M9Kkr 
http://joxi.ru/Y2L6EdMh9j6e7r

Подскажите пожалуйста, уже сил нету
Сервак node.js 
 "angular": "^1.6.7",
 "angular-resource": "^1.6.9",
 "angular-route": "^1.6.9",

Comment: проблема решилась подключением всех файлов в шаблоне начиная со /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась подключением всех файлов в шаблоне начиная с /